# How many people play basketball?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Question Claim: In a group of 500 people. 50% of the people are men. 10% of the people play basketball. How many men play basketball?

Can this even be done? One of the options is: Not enough information.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO this cannot be done.  10% can be entirely men or entirely the other group (could be kids or women or whatever else)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, here is what we know: there are $250$ men, $250$ women and $50$ people who play basketball, there can be any number from $0$ men basketball players to $50$ men basketball players.

Comment: How many great men were born in NYC in 1911? None, they were all babies.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar practice problems for standardized tests in the past. Some questions will explicitly tell you to assume that the same proportions of men and women play basketball; if it does not say to make that assumption, then you do not have enough information to answer the question.